# Can the pattern in this image, be represented by a simple mathematical model or expression?

Tags: geometry

[image: Accumulative Area of Circles]

The RED circle with the YELLOW center, is the start point.
The SOLID RED circle adds it's own area.
The GREEN circles add their area, plus the area closed up - 1 triangle.
The ORANGE circles add their own area, plus the area closed up - 2 triangles.

The solid line represents the direction of added circles.

Where the dotted line and solid line intersect, is the end of a series.

With each revolution, an ORANGE 'step' is added, to each grouping of ORANGE, while each GREEN 'step', becomes exponentially further apart from the last.

i.e. Starting at the first ORANGE circle, the pattern repeats as such (**bold** numbers are ORANGE:
**1**-1-**1**-1-**1**-1-**1**-1-**2**-1-**1**-1- O-G-O-G-O-G-O-G-OO-G-O-G-
**2**-1-**2**-1-**2**-1-**2**-1-**3**-1-**2**-1- OO-G-OO-G-OO-G-OO-G-OOO-G-OO-G-
**3**-1-**3**-1-**3**-1-**3**-1-**4**-1-**3**-1- OOO-G-OOO-G-OOO-G-OOO-G-OOOO-G-OOO-G-

If the diameter of the circle is 1", the area of the circle is 0.78539816,
and the area of the triangles are 0.04051151 each.

My current usage works well as a lookup table, I just want to see if it's possible to unbind it from that form.

Input = Number of Circles
Output = Total Area (including spaces)